# Creating sentences with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, semantics

I'm so obsessed with semantics and I'd like to create meaningful sentences through ASP.NET MVC's route rules which semantically describe the action. For example, I want to assign an article to some categories, and to do that, I'd like to have these URLs:

`/assign/article-name/to-categories`

which should have this rule:

`assign/{articleName}/to-categories`

and

`/assign/article-name/to/category-title/category`

which should have this rule:

`assign/{articleName}/to/{categoryTitle}/category`.

Some examples of desired URLs are:

`assign/seo/to/computer/category`, or `assign/how-to-drive-fast/to/general-knowledge/category`, or URLs like that.

The problem is that, I'm not professional at MVC routing and I can't make this work. Any help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following route definition should work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Assign",
    "assign/{articleName}/to/{categoryTitle}/category",
    new { controller = "Articles", action = "Assign" }
);
```

where you would have an `ArticlesController`:

```
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Assign(string articleName, string categoryTitle)
    {
        // TODO: handle the assigning
        return Content(string.Format("{0} {1}", articleName, categoryTitle), "text/html");
    }
}
```

Now for example the following request `assign/seo/to/computer/category` will be routed to the `Assign` action which will be passed `articleName = seo` and `categoryTitle = computer`.